# A variable or/with a default value in a Phoenix template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

What's the more elegant and shorter way to do this in Phoenix/Elixir?

```
<title><%= @page_title %></title>
```

I can, of course,  define `@page_title` in each action of each controller, but I want it to have a default value if I haven't defined  it in an action and and haven't passed it to a template.

How can I do that? This doesn't work:

```
<title><%= @page_title || "my title" %></title>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you access the variable through the `assigns` map with the bracket syntax, you won't get an error if the variable is not set; instead you'll get `nil`, which you can chain with `||` to provide a default value:

```
<title><%= assigns[:page_title] || "my title" %></title>
```